# You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I have spent all morning looking through SO for similar posts, and tried everything suggested and yet I can't find a solution to the problem.

I have added my app bundle to Google Play and have set up an internal testing release. So far so good. Google Play have given me a URL to download the app, but when I try I get a pop up on Google Play showing 'You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device'

I uninstalled the debug device I was using from Android Studio on my mobile device (Huawei) using Settings-> Apps -> Uninstall App

Here are the things I have tried:

1. I have gone back in to my device in to Settings -> Apps and can not see my app listed (and doesn't appear on a search)
2. I only have one user on my device. I don't seem to have a Guest account that it could be installed on;
3. I set up ADB and using 'adb shell pm list packages' from CMD I can see the list of many of the app packages on my device, but this one isn't there!
4. I have restarted my device after the uninstall;
5. Went in to 'data/' on my mobile device, and again can not see anything related to this app;

If I can't see the app on my device, and I can't find the package still on the device using adb - how can I find and delete whatever data Google Play can still see, so I can finally test out my app!?

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed any debug build or release build in your device earlier
and not seeing it in installed apps.

Connect your device and just run this command, replacing com.packagename with your app's package name

```
adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename
```

Comment: You just saved me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Very strange but I have an answer which seemed to work for me. So if you have gone through all the options from other SO posts (i.e. the list above) and it still will not work I tried installed it using Google Play on the PC, rather than on the mobile device.

I used the link from Google Play Console on my PC web browser. I clicked to install the app and it asked me which device I wanted to install to. I selected my mobile device from the list, and it pushed it out to my mobile and it appeared in seconds.

I can't answer why Google Play on my device wouldn't allow the install, but Google Play on my PC (which only pushed out to my mobile anyway) would ..... but if all else fails, it may be worth trying.